# How can I debug a "division by zero" error in postgresql

Tags: sql, debugging, postgresql

I am using many different views and plpgsql functions/aggregates in a single SELECT. When I run this SELECT on certain data sets, I get a `division by zero` error. Unfortunately, I don't get any details where exactly the division by zero occurs.

Is there I good way to pinpoint the exact place where the problem occurs?

Comment: Where do you get that message? Is it the whole message?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Excellent point! I got the error in my SQL IDE (Aqua Data Studio). When running the same code in psql I get quite a bit of context information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the same code in psql will yield more helpful information, like:

```
ERROR:  division by zero
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "mean_estimator_sfunc" line 10 during statement block local variable initialization
```

Comment: With default settings you should also find that information in your db log files.

Answer (score 0):

Post your function. Here's some good example from Oracle documentation on how to avoid your exception. Same can be done with SQL only:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm

```
DECLARE
  stock_price NUMBER := 9.73;
  net_earnings NUMBER := 0;
  pe_ratio NUMBER;
BEGIN
 pe_ratio :=
  CASE net_earnings
     WHEN 0 THEN NULL
     ELSE stock_price / net_earnings
  end;
END;
/
```

Comment: My problem is not fixing the `division by zero`, but locating the place where I need to fix it.

Comment: @@Karl Bartel - Post your code and maybe we can help you find where it is raised. In my personal opinion it would be better to make sure exceptions would never be raised in the code. If possible, I'd rewrite/add to the code to handle all possible exceptions after you find it, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. But it is far to much code to post here, and I was asking this question only to get a more targeted approach to finding the place where I forgot to handle the division by zero case appropriately. The psql output is mostly what I was looking for.